# Javascript urlencode query into href

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode

I wish to url encode the value.filelocation so as to have the link the js is producing sends info to my download script.

```
$(function() {
    $("a.dynamic").click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var destDiv = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').last().find('div[id]');
       $.getJSON( this.href, function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                destDiv.append("<th>Title</th>")
                destDiv.append("<th>TrackTime</th>")
                destDiv.append("<th>Composer</th>")
                destDiv.append("<th>Lyricist</th>")
                destDiv.append("<th>Song Link</th>")

               destDiv.append("<tr>")
               destDiv.append("<td>"+value.Title+"</td>")
               destDiv.append("<td>"+value.TrackTime+"</td>")
               destDiv.append("<td>"+value.Composer+"</td>")
               destDiv.append("<td>"+value.Lyricist+"</td>") 
               destDiv.append("<td><a href="+value.FileLocation+">Download Here</a></td>") 

               destDiv.append("<tr>");
            });
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've been down voted...is there a better way to ask the question?

Comment: What does a typical `value.FileLocation` look like?

Comment: <a href="private/XmasPrisonBlues.wma">Download Here</a>

Comment: Does the `FileLocation` include the `<a>...</a>` tags, or does it contain just the URL?

Comment: sorry just the url. I have the solution
destDiv.append("<td><a href='getsonginfo.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(value.FileLocation)+"'>Download Here</a></td>")

Comment: You should edit your question to explain the source of `FileLocation`, its typical values, _why_ it needs to be urlencoded, and what you want the result to be.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be

```
destDiv.append("<td><a href='getsonginfo.php?url="+encodeURIComponent(value.FileLocation)+"'>Download Here</a></td>")
```

Comment: But that would also encode the slash character. Does the link work after that?

Comment: it did encode the slash, you are right. But when I echo the GET value its fine

private/XmasPrisonBlues.wma

Comment: `encodeURI()` leaves URL-delimiters (such as `/`, `&`, `#`, ...) unchanged. Perhaps this is what you want.